# How to change "src" of a image (with multiple ID's) using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, src

I have been trying to change the `src` attribute of a image using `jquery`

This image tag has multiple ID's namely `blah1` and `one`

I need these two ID's for different purposes. So without changing the or removing an ID, how can I achieve this?

I tried but it didn't work.

Here's my `HTML`

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 ad-image">
       <label for="file1">
             <img id="blah1 one" src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
             <input type="button" value="Remove Photo" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="image-remove-btn-1">
             <small id="textCount" class="form-text text-center bold">Thumbnail</small>
       </label>
 </div>
```

And here's my `jquery`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function showImages() {
                    $("#one").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/200");
//                    $(':input').css('border', '1px solid red');
                }
            </script>
```

But it doesn't work. **It only works with one ID** but I really 2 ID's as mentioned above.

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in HTML id attributes. We can't fix things that aren't broken. If you need multiple ids for the same element, there's a bigger issue somewhere.

Comment: ^ it doesn't make sense for an element to have multiple ids.  One id is enough

Comment: Why do you need two ids? Maybe if you post your problem we could give you alternatives :).

Answer (score 3):

You can select an element with multiple IDs but it is fraught with issues and liable to break easily.  It's also very bad practise as it goes against well defined and expected standards.

However, this will select the element given in your description, but **only** if the ID is exactly as you posted.  If the 2 ID values are swapped around then this will stop working.

```js
$("[id='blah1 one']").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/200");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="blah1 one" />
```

That line of JS will return any element with the ID attribute of the value `blah1 one`.  If there are more than 1 then it will select and modify them all.  It's sometimes handy to know how to select by attribute values, but this is a bad example.

Realistically, you should be solving the actual problem, which is the fact that you have 2 ID values for an element.  Hacking your way around this issue today does not mean that it will still work tomorrow.

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments by Taplar, the following would achieve the same result and would account for the ID changing, but still containing the distinct value "one"...

```
$("[id~='one']")
```

That's a lot more reliable, but I still say the actual problem should be solved as there's no way to know what will happen in the future if you do something so fundamentally incorrect now.

Comment: You might also mention `[id~='one']` being able to select the attribute by word, so if the position of the one changed, it would still work.  But I agree, the bigger issue needs to be resolved.  Attribute selectors are less performant than id lookups.

Comment: Nice hack. :) This implies that `$( '[id*="one"]' )` will also work.

Comment: @Shilly `*='one'` would also match `onetime` as it's partial string, not whole word

Comment: While both are correct, I'd shy away from them more than the answer I've proposed because they could match other values.  It's just all horrible :p

Comment: `~=` will not match other values.  it's a word match, so the value has to be on it's own, or only have a string terminator or space on either side.  Unless you mean potentially matching other elements with that same id. (which would be yet another issue ;) )

Comment: If we go that route, we'd shy away from all 3 versions to begin with and just stick to valid HTML. ;)

Comment: @Taplar Apologies - I've learned something new today.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function showImages() {
      $("#one, #two, #three").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/200");
 }
```

You can give a list selector separated by a comma.